# How to create maximum value composite using terra r package?

Tags: r, terra

I want to create a maximum value composite raster by taking maximum values from each band of a raster stack. I am using the following code

```
library(terra)
library(RStoolbox)

rast1 <- rast(lsat)

#Create two raster stacks
rast2 <- rast(lsat)
random_nums <- runif(length(rast2), min = 0.3, max = 0.5) # a set of random numbers the size of the image
rast2[] <- rast2[] + random_nums 

rast3 <- rast(lsat)
random_nums <- runif(length(rast3), min = 0.1, max = 0.4) # a set of random numbers the size of the image
rast3[] <- rast3[] - random_nums 

#Create a stack of all the rasters
s <- c(rast1, rast2, rast3)

#Create a maximum value composite 
b1 <- tapp(s, index=c(1,8,15,2,9,16,3,10,17,4,11,18,5,12,19,6,13,20,7,14,21), 
           fun=max)
b1
```

Now it is giving me 21 layers. But the output should have 7 bands with each band made of by taking the maximum of rast1, rast2 and rast3 i.e. the band1 of b1 should take the maximum of band1 of rast1, 2 and 3. Likewise for b2 to b7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data

```
library(terra)
r1 <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=7)
set.seed(1)
r1 <- init(r1, runif)
r2 <- init(r1, runif)
r3 <- init(r1, runif)
```

The most straightforward way to get the *parallel* maximum cell values (the maximum value for each cell and each layer, across SpatRasters):

```
m1 <- max(r1, r2, r3)
```

Or create a SpatRasterDataset and use `app`

```
d <- sds(r1, r2, r3)
m2 <- app(d, max)
```

I would not recommend it as it is unnecessarily complex, but you *can* also do that with `tapp` like this:

```
i <- rep(1:7, 3)
i
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
s <- c(r1, r2, r3)
m3 <- tapp(s, i, fun=max)

m3
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 7  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : memory 
#names       :             X1,             X2,             X3,             X4,             X5,             X6, ... 
#min values  :   1.808664e-01,   0.000000e+00,  2.803072e-309, -6.884876e-311,   0.000000e+00,   0.000000e+00, ... 
#max values  :   9.926841e-01,  3.131513e-294,  1.536768e+277,  3.202245e+307,  3.046950e+294,  1.047578e+296, ...
```

Note that the layers with the same index are grouped. So for what you want you should only have seven numbers, each occurring three times.